# Reading in Parameters to Objects

Tags: object, pointers, cin

I am attempting to read in data to the person and car object so that I can store that data into an array.

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>

    using namespace std;

        class Person 
    {
        public:

            Person(string name, int age) { cout << "\n\tBuilding a Person";} //constructor 
        ~Person() { cout << "destructing Person";} //destructor 

        //accessor methods

        string GetName () {return name;}
        int GetAge () {return age;}



        private:
            string name;
            int age;
    };


    Person::Person (string pname, int page) 

           {
               name = pname;
               age = page;
           }

    class Car 
    {
        public:
            Car(string model, Person* owner, Person* driver) { cout<< "building a car";}
            ~Car() { cout << "destructing a car";} 

            //accessor methods

            string GetModel () {return model;}
            Person* GetOwner () {return owner;}
            Person* GetDriver() {return driver;}


        private:
            string model;
            Person* owner;         // pointer to owner which is an object of class person.
            Person* driver;       // pointer to driver which is an object of class person. 

    };



    Car::Car (string Carmodel, Person* Carowner, Person* Cardriver) // car object to hold car model, carowner, and car driver.
    {

        model = Carmodel;
        owner = Carowner;
        driver = Cardriver;

    }


    int main()
    {

        vector<Car*> dealership; //vector pointer of car objects. 

        vector<Person*> people; //vector pointer of person objects. 

        string n;
        int a;


        Person* user = new Person(n, a);
```

When I attempt to read in data to the below variables I receive an error no operator                  matches these operands. How can I get user input into the the above person object?

```
cin << n;  
cin << a;

Car* vehicle;

cout << "please enter the name of a person and a car model" << '\n';

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
cin >> n;
cin >> a;
```